# How to Add constraints programmatically to default textLabel and accessoryView of tableView cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I have a cell and since i wanted the default behaviour i am using the following way -

```
returnCell.textLabel.text = @"Some long text Some long text";
returnCell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
returnCell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

UISwitch *toggleSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
returnCell.accessoryView = toggleSwitch;

[returnCell.contentView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
[returnCell.textLabel setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

[returnCell addVisualConstraints:@"H:|[contentView]|"
                            forViews:@{@"contentView":returnCell.contentView}];
[returnCell addVisualConstraints:@"V:|[contentView]|"
                            forViews:@{@"contentView":returnCell.contentView}];
```

Now the problem that i have is, the text if small works fine but if it's long it goes behind the switch....

Now my question is how do i avoid this and add constraints to solve this problem between my textLabel and accessoryView(UISwitch) both of which are defalt and not added as subView to contentView of cell??

Thanks in advance!!! Please help.

Comment: It's better to go with constraints.

Comment: preferable to create a custom xib cell

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate **contentView** constraints until find **trailing** constraint with the **textLabel** and increase/decrease it's constant accroding to first item til it be away some amount from the switch(accessoryView)